# string to enum using parsing and reflection

Tags: c#, string, parsing, reflection, enums

I am reading a string and matching this string to one of the enum values that I have in the following line:

```
(DataType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DataType), row[0], true);
```

Is there an alternative way or more effient way to match a string with enum ? I heard that this can be done using reflection, is that possible ? any hint ? would it be more effient ?

Comment: do you want to know that enum value exists with same string name??

Comment: I am adding this string as an enum to a list<enum>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're definately doing this right IMO. What you might be confusing it with is that often people mark-up enums with a `DescriptionAttribute` to go the other way - converting an enum to a string for display purposes:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
  [Description("This is value One")]
  Value1,
  [Description("This is value Two")]
  Value2
}
```